# Problem books for nonlinear functional analysis?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, book-recommendation, nonlinear-analysis

> Recently I have started reading variational methods application to nonlinear PDE and hamiltonian systems written by Michael Struwe. The book doesn't contains any problems so I want any supplementary **problem books** on this subject nonlinear functional analysis as a companion to this please anyone help and suggest books?

Comment: [This](https://it.scribd.com/doc/79044749/Brezis-Analyse-Fonctionnelle-Recueil-De-Problemes-Et-Exercices-Polycopie) is the exercise set for the book "Analyse fonctionelle" of Haim Brezis, it should be roughly the same kind of mathematics. It is in French, though. The exercises have been translated in English and incorporated into the newer version of Brezis' book, which is called "Sobolev spaces and PDE" (or something like that)